# How to reset ordered list numbering in CSS

Tags: html, css, listitem

How can I reset the numbering for nested ordered lists.

Running this snippet, give me an output like this:

- List 1
- List 2
- List 3

  1. List 1
  2. List 2
  3. List 3

     - List 1
     - List 2
     - List 3

       ```
       3.1. List 1
       3.2. List 2
       3.3. List 3
               3.3.1. List 1
               3.3.2. List 2
               3.3.3. List 3
                       3.3.3.1. List 1
                       3.3.3.2. List 2
                       3.3.3.3. List 3
       ```

I want 3.1 to start with 1. How can I do this?
Do I need to use multiple counters? or a single one will do?
I'm not really used in using css counters.
The code works if it's a series of nested ordered list but when there is an unordered list inside it starts to fail. It still continues the numbering from the previous ordered list.

```css
ol {
    counter-reset: item 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul {
    counter-reset: item "";
}
ul:first-child>li {
    counter-reset: item "";
}
ul>li:before {
    content: " ";
    margin-right: 1em;
}
ol ul li:last-child {
    counter-reset: item "";
}
ol>li:before {
    counter-increment: item;
    content: counters(item, ".")".  ";
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul">
    <li class="li">List 1</li>
    <li class="li">List 2</li>
    <li class="li">List 3
        <ol class="ol">
            <li class="li">List 1</li>
            <li class="li">List 2</li>
            <li class="li">List 3<ul class="ul">
                    <li class="li">List 1</li>
                    <li class="li">List 2</li>
                    <li class="li">List 3
                        <ol class="ol">
                            <li class="li">List 1</li>
                            <li class="li">List 2</li>
                            <li class="li">List 3
                                <ol class="ol">
                                    <li class="li">List 1</li>
                                    <li class="li">List 2</li>
                                    <li class="li">List 3
                                        <ol class="ol">
                                            <li class="li">List 1</li>
                                            <li class="li">List 2</li>
                                            <li class="li">List 3</li>
                                        </ol>
                                    </li>
                                </ol>
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Edit: I wasn't still able to do this, even with multiple reset counter. Is there any hope for this?

Comment: @AndrewL64, thanks, but i also want the nested ordered list to follow the previous numbering. So that if the parent is an ordered list, the numbering will be inherited and it will only reset if it's an ordered list.

Comment: Oh ok. Let me try fiddling with the fiddle.

Comment: thanks, i've been struggling with for quite a long time now. if only i can remove `3` for the nested ordered list.

Comment: so where you have 3.1 you want to have 1.3.1 or only 1?

Comment: @GrávujMiklósHenrich, i want to restart the numbering at 1, if the parent is not an ordered list.

Answer (score 2):

You can view my case:

[image]

We just need to reset at the first child

```
.tos ol > li {
    counter-increment: listNumbering;
    list-style: none;
}
.tos ol > li:before {
    content: counter(listNumbering) '. ';
}
.tos ol > li:first-child {
    counter-reset: listNumbering;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't it break the previous style? I mean, if you mix this with default not-nested list items, they could have a different appearance. (Btw a working solution, so +1)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a new, different, counter to start when the `ol` is within an `ul` within an `ol`:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ol>li:before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: counters(item, ".")".  ";
}

ol ul ol {
  counter-reset: subitem 0;
}

ol ul ol>li:before {
  counter-increment: subitem;
  content: counters(subitem, ".")".  ";
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul">
  <li class="li">List 1</li>
  <li class="li">List 2</li>
  <li class="li">List 3
    <ol class="ol">
      <li class="li">List 1
        <ol class="ol">
          <li class="li">List 1</li>
          <li class="li">List 2</li>
          <li class="li">List 3</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li class="li">List 2</li>
      <li class="li">List 3
        <ul class="ul">
          <li class="li">List 1</li>
          <li class="li">List 2</li>
          <li class="li">List 3
            <ol class="ol">
              <li class="li">Sub List 1</li>
              <li class="li">List 2
                <ol class="ol">
                  <li class="li">List 1</li>
                  <li class="li">List 2</li>
                  <li class="li">List 3
                    <ol class="ol">
                      <li class="li">List 1</li>
                      <li class="li">List 2</li>
                      <li class="li">List 3</li>
                    </ol>
                  </li>
                </ol>
              </li>
              <li class="li">List 3
                <ol class="ol">
                  <li class="li">List 1</li>
                  <li class="li">List 2</li>
                  <li class="li">List 3</li>
                </ol>
              </li>
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

According to [w3 document](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/lists.html#h-10.2), you can directly define `value` prop to implement it.

```
<ol>
<li value="30"> makes this list item number 30.
<li value="40"> makes this list item number 40.
<li> makes this list item number 41.
</ol>
```